# Getting Polygons to display multiple variables using a stripped color scheme in ArcMap

Tags: mapping, gis, arcgis, arcmap

I am creating a map in which i want a polygon to display two separate variables within it. Therefore I want a stripped polygon relating to both the keys from the separate factors however I have no idea on how to do this. I messed around with multiple attributes on the properties section and could get the two variables up however could see no way of making the polygon display them both.

Thank you, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is partially manual, but you are going to have to make a separate category within one of the fields that identifies the multivariate features. You could also create a new layer that is a selection of these features. Once you have that, go to the layer properties and display the features as 'Categories - Unique values, many fields' and hit the 'Add All Values' button. Once the categories are populated select the one you are interested in and pick a hatched symbol such as 'Radiation Overlay'. Then go to the Symbol Property Editor (double-click the symbol) and modify the two layers that make up the hatched symbol. You need to adjust the color, line thickness, offset, etc. until you get it to look the way you want. Probably not as auto as you wanted, but it will satisfy display purposes.